# Rails 3 custom route not recognized by *_path method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, custom-routes

Is there a way to make sure a custom route is recognized by the `*_path` method?

I've got a resource, and a custom route to the same controller:

```
resources :news, :only => [:index, :show], :path => :nieuws
match '/nieuws/:cat/:id/:slug', :to => 'news#show'
match '/nieuws/:id/:slug', :to => 'news#show'
```

This is working fine, and when requesting `http://www.example.com/nieuws/category/1/slug` it will show the correct news item. The problem is that I want to use the `news_path` method to link to my news items. To achieve this I have added the following code to my news item model:

```
def to_param
  if news_category
    "#{news_category.slug}/#{id}/#{slug}"
  else
    "#{id}/#{slug}"
  end
end
```

When not using `/` to seperate the cat, id and slug it will work fine, but when using the `/` the  news_path method fails and the requested page displays:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news", :id=>#<NewsItem id: 1...etc
```

My `rake routes` output:

```
news_index GET /nieuws(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"news"}
news       GET /nieuws/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news"}
               /nieuws/:cat/:id/:slug(.:format) {:controller=>"news", :action=>"show"}
               /nieuws/:id/:slug(.:format)      {:controller=>"news", :action=>"show"}
```

I already tried to add `, :id => /[0-9]+\/.+/` to the end of my resource route, this enables usage of a `/` but because it just uses a regex I'm unable to get the `:cat` parameter from the URL

So, is there a way to make sure my custom route is recognized by the `news_path` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are using `to_param` in a way that it's not supposed to be used. if you have a `to_param` method there should also be a `from_param` method as a finder and it should always be mapped to a token and not to a path. so i.e. `"#{news_category.slug}-#{id}-#{slug}"` instead of `"#{news_category.slug}/#{id}/#{slug}"`.

if you wan't to separate by path segments you need to put that into your `news_path` call like this:

```
news_path(news, :cat => news_category.slug, :slug => slug)
```

see the guides for more advise: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the solution you gave me will genarate a link that looks like this `www.example.com/nieuws/2?cat=category&slug=slug`. What I'm trying to achieve is `www.example.com/nieuws/category/2/slug` or `www.example.com/nieuws/2/slug` for items without a category. Is there another way to do this while still using `news_path` or is the only solution to create my own url/path method in my model?

Comment: you can make named routes with the `:as` option and then use those instead of the `news_path` method.